# Installing Mujoco from AI gym onto Windows 10(For research)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I've been trying to download and play with the Open gym software that past two days. Specifically the Mujoco which I'm planning to use for research.

After some trials and tribulations actually figuring out how to use the terminal(I'm using the BASH terminal on windows 10), I finally downloaded all the files from open gym, gym.openai doc , onto my desktop.

when I try to run any of the python files, it gives me this error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mujoco_py/config.py", line 33, in init_config
raise error.MujocoDependencyError('To use MuJoCo, you need to either populate ~/.mujoco/mjkey.txt and ~/.mujoco/mjpro131,
  or set the MUJOCO_PY_MJKEY_PATH and MUJOCO_PY_MJPRO_PATH environment variables appropriately.
  Follow the instructions github /openai/mujoco-py for where to obtain these.')
mujoco_py.error.MujocoDependencyError: To use MuJoCo, you need to either populate ~/.mujoco/mjkey.txt and ~/.mujoco/mjpro131,
  or set the MUJOCO_PY_MJKEY_PATH and MUJOCO_PY_MJPRO_PATH environment variables appropriately.
  Follow the instructions on github /openai/mujoco-py for where to obtain these.
```

Which takes me here: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py

Of course it states that Mujoco isn't open sourced. So I went along with the trial program, got the license key and it tells me to download the binaries.

Which is not found.

https://roboti.com/active/mjpro131_windows.zip

Don't know how to proceed from here. Any helps would be appreciated. It's for research.

**By the way** I took the `https` and `.com` out of my links because stackexchange wouldn't let me post otherwise.